# Imagery horizontal accuracy

Tags: imagery

I am trying to determine if the following meets ASPRS Positional accuracy standards.

3 inch [7.5 cm] GSD     =   0.87 foot (27 cm) RMSE x / RMSE y Horizontal Accuracy Class
+/- 2.1 feet [65 cm] at a 95% confidence level